# How to use Alert box on button click in selenium by using web driver in java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Please help me Tester, i am frustrated this point i have apply more and more code but no solution found again and same message show.

................................................................................
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: **Unexpected modal dialog (text: Meal Added to Shopping List)**: Meal Added to Shopping List
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Saurabh', ip: '192.168.3.21', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 87eb9958-85a9-4571-8bbd-663fdaad2ad0

Comment: You need to be giving more than just the error you've recieved. Ideally you'd need to supply the section of your automation code which triggers the error, and if possible the code of what you're testing at that point to allow troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks dear for your reply finally my problem solved....

Comment: Useful..please give thumbs up!!